# Error when passing shapefile to PostGIS through submit button and PHP

Tags: postgis, shapefile, php

I have the following issue when I try to pass a shapefile to PostGIS.
When I run this part of code through the terminal:

```
shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /var/www/dkar/MarCO/Code/python/output/cluster/clusterNodes_.shp | psql -h localhost  -p **** -d ****** -U *******
```

It works perfectly and a new table in PostGIS is created, but when I try to do the same through a PHP script which I execute on a submit button then I get an error. I can not say for sure what's the error why I run the whole process through PHP exec so I just get an error code 2.

Also when I do the process through the terminal, I am asked for entering the db password. I also tried to include the password in the command like:

```
     `... -W password`
```

but it didn't make any difference.

The whole thing runs smoothly locally but it doesn't work in the remote server.

Any ideas what I might miss here?

Perhaps the path to the shapefile should be different in each case?

Comment: Try to run you php file on terminal with `/path/to/php -f your-file.php`, it can be related to which user is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related with the security authentication of PostgreSQL.
After adjusting this in the configuration of the database I was able to login automatically using this:

```
shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /var/www/dkar/MarCO/Code/python/output/cluster/clusterNodes_.shp | psql -U username -d databaseName
```

Hope this helps someone.